# Validate an ip in dash (not bash)

Tags: shell, sh, dash-shell

I am trying to validate an ip address within a dash script. I've found many ways to achieve the same with bash such as in [linuxjournal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/validating-ip-address-bash-script)

Basically what is does is a comparision using this:

```
if [[ $ip =~ '^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$' ]]; then
  do something
fi
```

Is there any way to get the same with dash?

**UPDATE:** This is the final script that does what I needed:

```
#In case RANGE is a network range (cidr notation) it's splitted to every ip from 
# that range, otherwise we just keep the ip
if echo $RANGE | grep -E -q '^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\/[0-9]{1,2}$'; then
    IPS=`prips $RANGE -e ...0,255`
    if [ "$?" != "0" ] ; then
        echo "ERROR: Not a valid network range!"
        exit 1
    fi
elif echo $RANGE | grep -E -q '^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$'; then
    IPS="$RANGE"
else
    echo "$RANGE no is not a valid IP address or network range"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: An IP address is just a 32-bit number.  You're asking for dotted-quad notation, but remember that decimal and hex notation are just as valid.  `0x1020304` and `16909060` are the same as `1.2.3.4`.

Comment: I only need validation for human error, no one other than me and my coleagues will use this script, so I can choose a notation and stick to that.

Comment: With regard to your final regexp, you might also represent it as something a bit shorter: `^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\/[0-9]{1,2}$`

Comment: You're using a bunch of different external commands, while it is quite possible to do this nice and cleanly using only `dash` builtins. (See my response below if you're curious as to how.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are happy with the validation string:

```
$ s='[0-9]\{1,3\}'
$ echo $ip | grep > /dev/null "^$s\.$s\.$s\.$s$" &&
  echo $ip is valid
```

Note that this accepts invalid ip addresses like 876.3.4.5

To validate an ip, it's really not convenient to use a regular expression.  A relative easy thing to do is:

```
IFS=. read a b c d << EOF
$ip
EOF

if ( for i in a b c d; do
        eval test \$$i -gt 0 && eval test \$$i -le 255 || exit 1
    done 2> /dev/null )
then
    echo $ip is valid
fi
```

Comment: Great, the only issue is that I need the -E flag to get the regex evaluated (or using egrep)
Thanks so much

Comment: Extended regular expressions should only be needed if you use s='[0-9]{1,3}'.  If you escape the brackets, basic regular expressions should work.  (Ah, you made your comment prior to my edit...)

Comment: Also, the redirection thing is a bit weird.  Just use `egrep -q "regex"` instead.

Comment: @ghoti I've always avoided -q for portability reasons, but just discovered that it is specified in the Open Group spec which is probably portable enough!

Comment: @ghoti On the other hand, grep -q could be considered bloat: http://harmful.cat-v.org/cat-v/

Comment: Whether it's bloat is up for debate.  A grep with redirection is guaranteed to traverse every line of input, whereas the `-q` behaviour could be to exit after the first match.  Where does one draw the line?  Is it better to have a whole 'nuther tool, "gree" for example, to Globally search for a RE, then Exit?

Answer (score 1):

You can build a `case` statement, although it will be more verbose than a regex.  On the other hand, you avoid spawning any external processes, and it might be easier to read and maintain to boot.

```
if case $ip in
    # Invalid if it contains any character other than number or dot
    # Invalid if it contains more than three dots
    # Invalid if it contains two adjacent dots
    # Invalid if it begins with a non-number
    # Invalid if it ends with a non-number
    *[!.0-9]* | *.*.*.*.* | *..* | [!0-9]* | *[!0-9] ) false ;;
    # Invalid if it contains a number bigger than 255:
    #  256-259 or 260-299 or 300-999 or four adjacent digits
    *25[6-9]* | *2[6-9][0-9]* | *[3-9][0-9][0-9]* | *[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]* ) false;;
    # Verify that it contains three dots
    *.*.*.* ) true ;;
    # Failing that, invalid after all (too few dots)
    *) false ;;
esac; then
    echo "$ip" is valid
fi
```

Notice the funky use of a `case` statement (returning either true or false) as the condition in an `if` statement.

This is slightly stricter than the regex in that it requires each octet to be less than 256.

Comment: I would not love to have to debug a function like that... :/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small `dash` shell function *which does not use **any** external commands* and that checks if an IPv4 address is valid. It returns true if the address was correctly formatted, false otherwise.

I've tried to explain the magic in my comments.

```
valid_ip() {
    local IP="$1" IFS="." PART           # make vars local, get arg, set $IFS
    set -- $IP                           # split on $IFS, set $1, $2 etc.
    [ "$#" != 4 ] && return 1            # BAD: if not 4 parts
    for PART; do                         # loop over $1, $2 etc.
        case "$PART" in
            *[!0-9]*) return 1           #   BAD: if $PART contains non-digit
        esac
        [ "$PART" -gt 255 ] && return 1  #   BAD: if $PART > 255
    done
    return 0                             # GOOD: nothing bad found
}
```

With this function you can test your IP address, e.g. to abort your script if the IP address is invalid:

```
if valid_ip "$IP"; then
    echo "ERROR: IP address '$IP' is invalid" >&2
    exit 4
fi
```